# What is the encoding used by ASCII character set?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ascii

I know UNICODE character set follows the UTF encoding style. But does ASCII character set follow any encoding style?

Comment: ASCII _is_ a character-encoding scheme

Comment: I'm confused. In C++ if you use wchar_t , it will use UNICODE character set with a UTF-16 encoding, is what I read. So is there any similarity with ASCII set? Or ASCII is an encoding itself? If yes then what character set does it use?

Comment: ASCII is a subset of unicode, see basic latin in unicode thats the ASCII subset

Comment: @PyGamer0 Other way around.  UTF is a superset of ASCII.  ASCII came first.  OP: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @Zeph_The_Hungry_Loli `wchar_t` is not any specific encoding, it's just 16-bit characters in whatever encoding you put there. Or just 16-bit numbers.

Comment: You might be thinking of ANSI which is some old crap still used in Windows. ASCII is very [simple](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unicode, formally, is the Standard. It can be implemented by different character encodings. The Unicode standard defines Unicode Transformation Formats (UTF): UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32, and several other encodings.
UTF-8 uses one to four bytes per code point and, being compact for Latin scripts and ASCII-compatible. The first 128 code points represent the ASCII characters, which means that any ASCII text is also a UTF-8 text.